# Does browser take care of dom changes matching?

Tags: javascript, dom, replace, match

Let's say I have this code on my site:

```
<div class="test">hello</div>
```

Then I replace it with this, for example with innerHTML:

```
<div class="test2">Hello there</div>
```

It changes on the site like expected. But what if I replace it with this? (an exact match of what is already there)

```
<div class="test">hello</div>
```

**Question**

Will the browser check if there is an exact match before replacing DOM content or do I need to check that myself?

About speed. Is it faster to first make a check if the content match and if it does not match replace it, else do nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

everytime you use `innerHTML` , dom tree is updated by the browser.